# Invalid variance

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have the following interface definition:

```
public interface IResEnume<out TModel> : IEnumerable<TModel> where TModel : IModel
{
}
```

where IModel is

```
public interface IModel
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

This works fine when the target framework is .NET 4.

I'm trying to port a class library to Windows Phone 7.1.

When doing this I get the following error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TModel' must be invariantly valid >on 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. 'TModel' is covariant.

If I remove the 'out' that line compiles, but then I get an error someplace else.

Comment: I think you have a co-variance problem... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `T` parameter on `IEnumerable<T>` is not covariant in Silverlight. Conveniently, MSDN says it *is* covariant, however in the community content, someone else points out the same thing:

> Despite the documentation above, the generic type parameter T does not appear to be covariant in Silverlight.

We can verify this in the Object Browser. In .NET Framework 4:

[image: .NET 4]

Notice the type declaration includes the `out`.

And for Windows Phone 7:

[image: Silverlight]

There is no `out` in Windows Phone `IEnumerable`. You cannot declare `TModel` covariant because `IEnumerable<T>` does not guarantee that it is a covariant. There is no reason it couldn't be this case; Microsoft just needs to update it.

**EDIT**: After some digging, looks like this is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/583165/co-contravariance-for-ienumerable-and-other-types) on Microsoft Connect which is marked as "fixed". It's likely been fixed for Silverlight 5; which Windows Phone is not yet using.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to do some refactoring.